# Get list of dictionary of two columns when grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use group by and aggregate my results by printing a list of dictionaries where one column serves as the key and the other as the value

My data is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'channel': 'one', 'hour': 6, 'rating':7.2},
    {'channel': 'one', 'hour': 7, 'rating':8.2},
    {'channel': 'one', 'hour': 8, 'rating':4.2},
    {'channel': 'two', 'hour': 6, 'rating':10.2},
    {'channel': 'two', 'hour': 7, 'rating':1.2},
    {'channel': 'two', 'hour': 8, 'rating':3.2},
])
```

I try the following

`df.groupby('channel').agg({'hour':list, 'rating':list}).reset_index()`

I can get a list of items

```
channel hour    rating
0   one [6, 7, 8]   [7.2, 8.2, 4.2]
1   two [6, 7, 8]   [10.2, 1.2, 3.2]
```

My intention is to get the following:
channel hour    rating_by_hour

```
0   one {6:7.2, 7:8.2, 8:4.2}
1   two {6:10.2, 7:1.2, 8:3.2}
```

I try the following: 
`df.groupby('channel').agg({'rating_by_hour':{df['hour']:df['rating']}}).reset_index()`

Naturally I get an error stating that 'series' objects are mutable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df[['hour','rating']].apply(tuple,1).groupby(df['channel']).apply(list).map(dict).reset_index()
Out[168]: 
  channel                                0
0     one   {8.0: 4.2, 6.0: 7.2, 7.0: 8.2}
1     two  {8.0: 3.2, 6.0: 10.2, 7.0: 1.2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer if i wanted to sum up the ratings?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another:

```
df.groupby('channel').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('hour')['rating']
                                       .to_dict()).reset_index()

channel     0
0   one     {6: 7.2, 7: 8.2, 8: 4.2}
1   two     {6: 10.2, 7: 1.2, 8: 3.2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer if i wanted to sum up the ratings?

Comment: you mean this `df.groupby('channel').agg([lambda x: x['rating'].sum(), lambda x: x.set_index('hour')['rating']
                                       .to_dict()])`

Comment: Yes, i was lazy.

Comment: My bad, cafe didn't work yet. I guess we can do groupby twice. It's convenient to do `groups=df.groupby('channel')`.